# Updating table view cells swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, multidimensional-array, row, indexpath

**BACKGROUND**

I have a simple bill splitting app that allows the users to assign a meal item to multiple people or users. When the meal is assigned to multiple people, the price is divided accordingly. The meal (which contains an item name and a price are the rows and the users are the sections.

When I delete a row, I want to delete the row, and update or alter certain other values (I basically want to reassign the price to one less person when an item is deleted from a user). My data model is a `multidimensional` `array`. Here it is:

```
 struct UserModel {
    var name: String
    var itemModels = [ItemModel]()

    init(name: String, itemModels: [ItemModel]? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        if let itemModels = itemModels {
            self.itemModels = itemModels
        }
    }
}

    struct ItemModel {
    var itemName: String
    var price: Double

    init(itemName: String, price: Double) {
        self.itemName = itemName
        self.price = price
    }
}
    class Data {
    static var userModels = [UserModel]()
    static var itemModels = [ItemModel]()
}
```

For example, in `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (contextualAction, view, actionPerformed: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) in

        let user = Data.userModels[indexPath.section].name
        let item = Data.userModels[indexPath.section].itemModels[indexPath.row].itemName
        let price = Data.userModels[indexPath.section].itemModels[indexPath.row].price


        ItemModelFunctions.removeFromUser(from: indexPath.section, remove: indexPath.row)

        var duplicate = Data.userModels.filter({$0.itemModels.contains(where: {$0.itemName == item})}).filter({$0.name != user}) 

        for i in 0..<duplicate.count {
            ???
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
        actionPerformed(true)
    }
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
}
```

The variable `var duplicate` returns an array of the other users who have the same item at the `indexPath.row`, but not the user(`indexPath.section`) who has the item. I know it sounds really confusing, but I can provide more code or `print` statements if needed.

Also in the `for loop`, I want to do something like this:

```
for i in 0..<duplicate.count {
    let oldPrice = duplicate[i].price
    let newPrice = oldPrice * duplicate.count
    duplicate[i].price = newPrice
}
```

But I can't access the price. I believe need an `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row`.

If you made it this far, thank you for taking the time. I feel like I need a nested loop, but I'm not sure how exactly to implement that. If there are any other easier ways to achieve this I'm open to any suggestions.

Thank you so much!

**EDIT:**
The marked answer worked! In case anyone else was having a similar issue this is what my final code looks like in the `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (contextualAction, view, actionPerformed: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) in

        let item = Data.userModels[indexPath.section].itemModels[indexPath.row]
        ItemModelFunctions.removeFromUser(from: indexPath.section, remove: indexPath.row)

        let duplicate = Data.userModels.filter({$0.itemModels.contains(item)})

        for i in 0..<Data.userModels.count {
            if let idx = Data.userModels[i].itemModels.firstIndex(of: item) {
                let oldPrice = Data.userModels[i].itemModels[idx].price

                let newPrice = oldPrice * Double(duplicate.count+1)

                Data.userModels[i].itemModels[idx].price = newPrice / Double(duplicate.count)
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
        actionPerformed(true)
    }
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this. Best of luck, please comment if it doesn't work. I am new to Swift :)

```
let actualItem = Data.userModels[indexPath.section].itemModels[indexPath.row]

for i in 0..<duplicate.count {
  if let idx = duplicate[i].itemModels.firstIndex(of: actualItem) {
     let oldPrice = duplicate[i].itemModels[idx].price
     duplicate[i].itemModels[idx].price = oldPrice * duplicate.count
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help! I can't actually update the item at the indexPath.section and indexPath.row. I need to access all of the other ones. But that's okay! Thank you.